# Casting IQueryable to another type throws error "System.NotsupportedException"

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework-6, iqueryable

```
Class Base
    Property Id as integer
End Class    

Class A 
    Inherits Base

    Property Name as string 
    Property Address as string 
End Class

Friend Function GetFamily(***Of T As Base***)(ent As SysEntities,
                              input As IQueryable(Of T)) As IQueryable(Of A)
-linq selector-

End Function
```

Actually T is of type A but I can not query the other parameters like Name, address as they are unknown at this stage. 
There is one solution to Mapp it using extension of Automapper(***ProjectTo(Of T)***) but I am not supposed to use that.

It is not working if someone can replay me a solution. As per the details provided at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.cast?view=netframework-4.8 it should work.

Please note I am not supposed to use Automapper for the same but the standard solution from Microsoft

Comment: Can you show the code you're working with?

Comment: What is `Value`? Is that supposed to be `valueOfA`? Why do you expect an object of type `A` to be able to be cast to type `B` when there is no relationship between the two classes?

Comment: The link you provided tells us this is not possible "depends on the implementation of the type of the source parameter.". Your only option would be to copy each field on at a time or maybe use some sort of serialization. What are you trying to do? Seems strange to have two classes with the same properties.

Comment: David G I have updated the question if it make sense now. Sorry if it looks hard to understand. You can ask me if it is still unclear.

Comment: Can you show what you are doing for the Linq? Considering the example you linked, I don't see why using `Cast(Of ClassA)` won't do what you want it to. Even possibly using `OfType(Of ClassA)` but that's more dependent on the expected input

Comment: Show your real code

Comment: To make it bit more clear please consider below,
Class A is a database table also. So data will be grabbed by dbContext and returned.
But in my generic repository I will pass T as dbModel only. Now I am here in the method while in code I am only seeing one property ID for input which is reflecting from T but in actual this contains all the properties but I am unable to select them. Hope it is clear now

Comment: you need to clarify your question by editing the question. It you talk specifically to somebody, you need to add @userName to your comment, so that user you talking to gets notified.